# Cancel new request instead of currently loading request when refreshing an image with Angular's $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular's timeout to refresh the contents of an image at a user-specified interval. When that interval is too low for the image to load (e.g. 1 second), each subsequent request cancels the previous one causing the image to never refresh.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools network tab showing canceled requests]

Instead of this behavior, I would like for the current request to complete and for subsequent requests to be canceled until that one is completed when requests collide. How can I do this?

The code that handles the refreshing:

```
$scope.setImagePath = function() {
  $scope.imagePath = $scope.camera.endpoint + '?decache=' + Math.random();
};
$scope.setImagePath();

$scope.refreshOnInterval = function() {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.setImagePath();
    $scope.refreshOnInterval();
  }, $scope.refresh);
};
$scope.refreshOnInterval();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884399/image-loaded-event-in-for-ng-src-in-angularjs). The event demonstrated there would provide the base for an implementation.

My suggestion is use the `imageonload` directive as a start. Instead of `alert`-ing something, update a variable with the loaded state of the image. Then, in your `$timeout` handler, check this state variable and do not call `setImagePath()` if the state is still loading. You would probably need to update the state variable in `setImagePath()` too.