# Is there a callback/promise for when images load when using ng-src?

Tags: angularjs

I have a system that generates QR codes for an invoice. The image for the QR code is pulled from another service online.

For my view I have

```
 <div class="jumbotron" ng-show="invoiceReady">
```

.. where I set invoiceReady to true once my JS calculates the various amounts.

```
    $scope.qrImgUrl = 'http://www.btcfrog.com/qr/bitcoinPNG.php?address=' + $scope.invoiceData.btcAddress + '&amount=' + $scope.invoiceData.btcAmount;
    $scope.invoiceReady = true;
```

But what I need to do is wait a little longer until the image loads in my view. As ng-show shows the invoice view.. but it takes a few seconds longer for the QR image to actually load.

```
<img ng-src="{{qrImgUrl}}" />
```

I could use $timeout to wait a couple more seconds to cover that image load time. And I'm curious if there is a way to programatically catch when the image actually does load?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image loaded event in for ng-src in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884399/image-loaded-event-in-for-ng-src-in-angularjs)

Comment: yip using that directive approach worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

Solution I found was to use a directive as shared by @hutingung above. And modified from the code I found here https://thinkster.io/egghead/directives-talking-to-controllers/

Create a directive..

```
angular.module('posBitcoinApp')
.directive('imageonload', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('load', function() {
            scope.$apply(attrs.imageonload);
        });
    }
};
});
```

In my view..

```
<img ng-src="{{qrImgUrl}}" imageonload="showInvoice()"/>
```

Then in my controller..

```
$scope.showInvoice = function() {
    $scope.invoiceReady = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ngSrc` directive won't help you with this, because basically it does nothing more than setting the `src` attribute of an `img` element.

However, there are ways of being notified when an image has loaded: see [How can I determine if an image has loaded, using Javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery)