# Rotate an image if width is greater than height

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm working with a mobile WebView and I'm fullscreening an image. In some scenarios I can prevent the image from getting too torn apart by rotating the image 90 degrees if the width of the image is greater than the height of the image.

I know I can rotate the image using the `css transform` property, but I can't quite figure out how to do the math for the size of the image.

All of the images are pulled from a remote location using `http`

**EDIT: I may have left out some important information!!**

I am using `ionic` and this specific element that I need to access is in an `$ionicModal` and is not actually a dom element, according the ionic moderators. Therefor I cannot use `document.getElementById` on it.

Comment: What don't you know? How to get the width or height with javascript or how to compare them?

Comment: I have no idea what "not a DOM element" means. If it's not in the DOM, then it's not going to be visible so I think they are mistaken.

Comment: Open your webpage, press F12, check the elements on the webpage and search for this specific element. I honestly doubt it's not part of the site...

Comment: @Bálint Any recommendations on how to do this via the iOS browser? This is a mobile application with many native features. It does not run on desktop.

Comment: @Hobbyist if you use Chrome, then by pressing the mobile icon on the top left corner, you can emulate any type of cellphone

Comment: @Bálint that will emulate the size of the mobile, it won't let you run a mobile app. He will need to use something like Ripple for Chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById("yourElement")
```

This returns the DOM element you want (in this case, an image). Using the object's `width` and `height` properties, you get the width and height of the image (obviously).

You need to check if `.width` is greater than `.height`, then set the transfrom property of the element

Answer (score 0):

As you load image from a remote address, wait for image to load and then get width and height:

```js
$('#myimage').on('load',function(){
   var img = document.getElementById('myimage'); 
   var width = img.clientWidth;
   var height = img.clientHeight;
   if (width>height){
     alert('Width is greater');
   }
   else{
      alert('Height is greater');
      //And do rotation if this is the right place
   }
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="myimage">
```

if You are using **ionic** you may access the element by ID using following code:

```
var $myimage=angular.element(document.getElementById("myimage"));
$myimage.on('load',function(){//Same  as above}
```

Comment: Yes. Please check last two lines

Comment: 'load' is never called.

Comment: For load function in angular please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884399/image-loaded-event-in-for-ng-src-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use JavaScript to add a class say 'wide image' with the following code:

```
Function tagImage {
      document.getElementByTagname('img').foreach(function (element) {
    if(element.width > element.height) {
       element.className += ' wide-image';
    }
 }
}
```

And then use media queries to transform those images as required. Or you could add this class only when Windows width is at a certain breakpoint as an alternative option.

Also if possible if all of your images can be given a class you could get them by the class selector.

If in ionic modal you have the height and width information available, and can conditionally add the 'wide-image' class then that should work too.

Comment: Accessing from mobile now, so that's the best I can do at the moment