# Get height of img tags generated with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a carousel who's images are being created with an ng-repeat. The width of these img tags have been set to 100%; and the height, auto. How do I get the height of the img tags programmatically since this value changes when the window is resized? I tried

```
$('#home-carousel img').load(function(){
    console.log($(this).height());
})
```

but it doesn't work since the imgs don't exist at that time.
Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; z-index:-1" id="home-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Here's where the problem is -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slides track by $index" class="item" ng-class="{active: $index == 0 }">
      <img src="{{slide.imgUrl}}">
    </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT:Okay so let me elaborate. This is what I'm trying to achieve:
So the images of the paint buckets are supposed to be lined exactly how it looks in this image; right at the bottom of where the background image ends

[image]

[image]

Problem is, since the width of the image is 100%, when the window is resized, this is what happens. So what I want to do is get the height of the img images in the carousel and position the paint bucket based on that

Comment: When and where do you want to get and use the height? Can you create a fiddle or something with your code snippet?

Comment: provide fiddle so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I solved this by doing this:
First, I used @Braden1996 's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884399/image-loaded-event-in-for-ng-src-in-angularjs) to get the initial height of the img tag when it's first loaded

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; z-index:-1" id="home-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slides track by $index" class="item" ng-class="{active: $index == 0 }">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.imgUrl}}" imageonload="imageLoaded()"><!--here-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
$scope.imageLoaded = function(){
  $('.grid-container').css('margin-top',$('#home-carousel').height()-100 );
}
```

and after that, changed the position of the paint buckets everytime the window is resized.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.grid-container').css('margin-top',$('#home-carousel').height()-100 );
})
```

NB: The `-100` is so the bucket doesn't fall right under the background image

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Angular's ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).
Also, after a quick search, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884399/image-loaded-event-in-for-ng-src-in-angularjs) - which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks for the ng-src tip. Doesn't solve this problem but its better than using src.

Comment: and the other link was also very helpful. I always wondered how to detect if an image is fully loaded. Thanks again