# Ionic - show splash screen until the first image loads

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen

I have an app in Ionic v.1 and on page where I have a list of articles, I would like to have a splash screen until the first image is completely loaded, not sure how to do that?

This is the controller:

```
module.exports = angular.module('coop.controllers')
.controller('ArticlesController', function($scope, ArticleService, $state, $ionicScrollDelegate, $location, $ionicPosition, $ionicConfig) {
  $scope.articles = ArticleService.all();

  $scope.$on('$ionicParentView.afterEnter', function(event, data) {
    $scope.videoPlaying = [];
    $ionicConfig.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);

    if (data.direction == 'back') {
      $scope.doRefresh();
    }
  });

  $scope.articleType = 'all';

  $scope.articleFilter = function(button) {
    $scope.articleType = button;

    $scope.doRefresh();
  };

  $scope.showBulletPoint = function(which) {
    return $scope.articleType == which;
  }

  $scope.like = function(article){
    article.userLiked = !article.userLiked;
    ArticleService.like(article)
  };

  $scope.doRefresh = function (){
    var articleType = $scope.articleType ? $scope.articleType : 'all';

    ArticleService[articleType]().$promise.then(function(data){
       $scope.articles = data;
    }).finally(function() {
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });
  };

  $scope.videoPlaying = [];
  $scope.playerVars = {
    controls: 0,
    showinfo: 0
  };

  $scope.playVideo = function(youtubePlayer, index) {
    $scope.videoPlaying[index] = true;
    youtubePlayer.playVideo();
  };

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterLeave', function(event, data) {
      $scope.videoPlaying = false;
      $ionicConfig.views.swipeBackEnabled(true);
      //youtubePlayer.stopVideo();
  });
});
```

And this the html:

```
<ion-view>
  <div class="row articles-header">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon-round"></button>
    <div class="right-icons">
      <!--<a class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-search-strong">
      </a>-->
      <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('all')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="showBulletPoint('all')"></i> Siste
      </a>
      <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('video')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="showBulletPoint('video')"></i> Video
      </a>
      <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('popular')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="showBulletPoint('popular')"></i> Populært
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ion-content class="articles-content">
    <ion-refresher pulling-icon="false" on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="article in articles" class="item-light">
        <div class="article">
          <a ng-if="authenticated" ng-show="article.external_media.length == 0"  ui-sref="main.article({id: article.id})" nav-direction="forward" class="article-image-link">
            <img class="img" src="{{ fileServer }}/imagecache/cover/{{article.cover_image}}">
            <h1>{{ article.title.split(' ', 7).join(' ') }}</h1>
          </a>
          <a ng-if="!authenticated" ng-show="article.external_media.length == 0"  ui-sref="main.articlePublic({id: article.id})" nav-direction="forward" class="article-image-link">
            <img class="img" src="{{ fileServer }}/imagecache/cover/{{article.cover_image}}">
            <h1>{{ article.title.split(' ', 7).join(' ') }}</h1>
          </a>
          <a ui-sref="main.article({id: article.id})">
            <div class="iframe" ng-show="article.external_media.length > 0 && article.external_media.image != ''">
              <img class="img" ng-src="{{ article.external_media[0].image }}">
              <h1>{{ article.title.split(' ', 7).join(' ') }}</h1>
              <div class="iframe-overlay">
                <div class="play">
                  <img class="playButton" src="icons/playRectangle.svg"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="row article-meta" ng-class="{ 'has-comments': article.enable_comments }">
          <a ng-click="like(article)" class="subdued col col-30">
            <img class="social-images" ng-src="icons/{{ article.userLiked ? 'heart' : 'heart-outline' }}.svg"/> Lik
          </a>
          <a ui-sref="main.article({id: article.id, gotoComments: true })" class="subdued col col-60" ng-if="article.enable_comments">
            <img class="social-images" src="icons/comment.svg"/> {{ article.commentCount }} Kommentarer
          </a>
          <a ui-sref="main.article({id: article.id})" nav-direction="forward" class="col col-10 article-link right">
            <img class="social-images" src="icons/arrow.svg"/>
          </a>
        </div>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to attach an `onLoad` handler to the images, and when the first image (or any other specific image, all, etc) have loaded you can remove your splash screen.

To do this we'll create a directive to handle the `onload` event, based on [this outstanding solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25609847/438581) from [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849417/peter), combined with the `$ionicLoading` loader.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic'])

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicLoading) {

  // Setup the loader
  $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0 
  });

  // Add a simple onLoad callback
  $scope.onLoad = function (id) {
    if (id === 0) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    }
  }

  $scope.items = [
    {img: 'http://placehold.it/5000x8000/f9009a/ffffff'}, 
    {img: 'http://placehold.it/5000x8000/f9009a/ffffff'}, 
    {img: 'http://placehold.it/5000x8000/f9009a/ffffff'}
  ];

});

// The imageonload directive
app.directive('imageonload', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('load', function() {
        //call the function that was passed
        scope.$apply(attrs.imageonload);
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Then use the directive:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" href="#">
  <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" imageonload="onLoad({{$index}})" id="img-{{$index}}" />
</ion-item>
```

When the app loads the `$ionicLoading` screen will be shown until the first image emits the `onload` event, causing the `$ionicLoading` screen to be removed.

For a working demo, see this [Ionic Play demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/e7c55c6abb80).

The loading screen may only be noticeable the first time you load the demo, and on subsequent loads you might need to do a hard refresh.